# Way to tell render() to use a different .tpl file?

Tags: 7, theming

I am working on a Global module (used by many sites). I have two .tpl files (`list.tpl` and `product.tpl`) that both use a 3rd .tpl (`product-images.tpl`).

In both list and product .tpls, this is called like:

```
  <div id="product-images">
    <?php print render($element['productImages']); ?>
  </div>
```

However, I want to change the way `product-images.tpl` appears in `product.tpl`. I want to say something like

> "If productImages is rendered within `product.tpl` use
>   `product-page-images.tpl`".

The tricky thing is a I cannot add any logic to the actual module's code it's self, as it is being used by many other sites and I don't want to break anything. I can only really alter the .tpl files within my site's theme.

Is there a way to provide perhaps and additional parameter to `render()` to have it use a different .tpl file?

Any help or advice is much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Have you changed the theme hook attached to this element?

Comment: @kevin, no as I do not want to mess around with the modules core files

Comment: So... how are you going to determine rendering logic without changing things via preprocessing them? What I meant was intercepting this element _before_ it is rendered and changing the #theme hook key to something of your creation (defined with hook_theme). No module altering necessary of what you didn't originally write.

Comment: @Kevin, I'm really sorry but I just don't understand what you mean.